# SFMC Multiple Business Unit Architecture Efficiency

Tags: marketing-cloud

A client has a single SFMC (email only) BU configured & working.  All subscriber data resides in the Sales CRM cloud.  They want 10+ additional BUs setup and configured to deploy emails for separate divisions of the same organization.

When creating a new hierarchy BUs in SFMC:

- Does each BU require a unique cloud connector to sales cloud, or does just the root BU need the connector, to feed a Shared Data Extension?
- Does the root Sender Auth Package (SAP) & sender profiles cascade into the other BUs or need to be reconfigured, even when using the same sender domain?
- Whats the best method to control subscriber opt-in status (unsubscribes) across multiple BUs?

Basically, with a root BU already running, are the additional BU standup & configurations the same level of effort, or very easy because it uses the root BU previously configured components?

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer for this? I am curious about the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Even I'm curious to find answers to these questions. TIA

Answer (score 1):

1) In a context that include multiple Sales Cloud connections (I believe this is the case for you), you can switch to a multi-org configuration via Support (case). You cannot revert the multi-org setting, so Read all the documentation you can find, starting with the links below. If you do not work with the Sales Cloud Connector, then it is likely not worth going through.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5

2) SAP wise - I believe you have to configure it for each of the BUs, regardless of the hierarchy setup.

3) Subscribers wise - you can manage it at the BU level, but there is always an ALL Subscribers list that is SHARED among ALL BUs. The best way I can think to manage this, as of now, is by Permissions and Filters.